# .htaccess stub files to protect site with php session auth

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

Im trying to create a site where authorized users can download pdf files...
the pdf files are in the webroot auth is by php sessions...

so to protect files from hotlinking, i found a working solution

php:
at successful login write a new file named session id:

```
if($logged_in) {
    touch('auths/' . session_id());
}
```

then the .htaccess checks if the session id file is exists, if file is not exists its redirects to login..

```
# checks if a file named 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} PHPSESSID=(\w+)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/auths/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1
RewriteRule /* /login.php [L]
```

This is working so far, did a simple testing environment....

The issue is this needs to be combined with a cakephp app which uses the following .htaccess:

```
# CakePHP
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

So my question how could .htaccess modified so its only checking if the request is *.pdf and also works together with the cakephp rules...

Thank you !!

Comment: Do you use ACL for your application?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that combine .htaccess and CakePHP will do well. Both are different kind of software and don't have native communication method. Until you write your own module for Apache I don't think you'll make a good solution. On your place I'd rather read whole file to variable than print it with proper header. A memory costly solution but secure, server independent and pretty easy to modify in the future.